# Would this bass line be heard as 5/4 or 4/4?

Tags: time-signatures

Assuming no other instruments (such as drums, in particular) are providing any clues about the time signature, would the following bass line be heard by people as 5/4 or 4/4 (all quarter notes, all same volume):

G A A A A G A A A A G A A A A G G A A A :

IOW, would it be heard as:

[image: bass line presented in groups of 4 and 5]
?

Does it depend on what the listener is accustomed to hearing (the time signature is in the ear of the beharker)? IOW, would most people hear it as 4/4?

Comment: I have voted to reopen. This isn't a matter of opinion. The change in pitch will be perceived as an accent. It's the same principle used by metronomes that use a different pitch for the downbeat than on the other beats.

Comment: @Aaron - I've heard pieces in the Musescore website that my brain has interpreted as being in 3/4 time and 6/8 time depending on what I'm thinking of the piece at the time, so yes, it is opinion-based (those were real music with real running 8ths for melody and accompaniment, so pitch changes matter surprisingly little).

Comment: @Dekkadeci This question is about a specific bass line and 5/4 vs. 4/4. 3/4 vs. 6/8 is an entirely different matter, far more subjective, and the subject of many questions on this site that are open.

Comment: Voted to reopen for the reasons stated by @Aaron - though one clarification: I am assuming you also mean that the bass instrument *itself* isn't accenting the notes differently or providing other cues either.

Comment: @Aaron - With audio that doesn't accent any notes on downbeats such as most Musescore-original pieces, the issue is always the same: whether every X notes or every Y notes should be grouped together beat-or measure-wise. With 3/4 vs. 6/8, it's every 2 vs. every 3. With 4/4 vs. 5/4, it's every 4 vs. every 5.

Comment: @Dekkadeci As I understand your comment, you're speaking of how to notate such a piece; but that isn't the question here. This is simply about perception, and the perception in this case is unambiguous. The G will be perceived as the downbeat. Since pitch is the only element of change, that moment of change — when the G is heard — will be perceived as an emphasis.

Comment: Just to point out to everyone, it might help to hear the questions in this in inverted order: "1) Can people's familiarity with a given meter override melodic cues? I.e., if common time is so darn common, can a bias for it override some of the cues that help us construe meter? And then 2) for example, what about this contrived scenario?" Perhaps too much attention is being given to the example and not to the real question. Also IMO the example is so contrived as to force the answer "in this case, certainly not," but one could come up with a less deterministic scenario...

Comment: @AndyBonner - If you were just listening to a 4/4 - or even 3/4! - piece before listening to the sample in the question, I don't think you can force the answer "in this case, certainly not" anymore.

Comment: @Dekkadeci Meh, maybe that's an argument for "opinion-based" *, but I still think not. Now, if a metric pattern had already been established *in this piece* and we flowed seamlessly into this segment, sure (though even then I think it would disrupt my existing 4/4 or 3/4). But play in 4/4, stop, turn the page, continue with this, I think I'd be in 5 by the 3rd A (or at the worst, simply confused, but not comfortably in 4 or 3). (*Though I firmly believe that opposing As on a Q do not always prove that the Q "invited opinion-based As.")

Comment: @Нетвойне: Correct; picture a robot playing the notes

Answer (score 5):

In the scenario described, it would be heard as 5/4. Because there are no other contextual clues, the G would stand out from the texture and be perceived as "accented" — not in the sense of volume, but in the sense of having attention called to it by virtue of being different from the otherwise static A.

Comment: Unexplained dv - again?

Comment: @Tim I didn't downvote without explaining, but I'm downvoting now because the question is too subjective to support such an absolute answer as this.  Whether it is heard one way or another depends on the player and, much more to the point, on the hearer.

Comment: @phoog - so if the **question** is too subjective, **that's** what needs dving, not any answer, surely? And, listeners receive more than hearers, don't they? But, all that apart - dvers *should* be expected to validate their dvs, as I keep harping on about...

Comment: @Tim the question is too subjective for this answer to be appropriate; it's not necessarily too subjective in an absolute sense.  If you prefer, I could rephrase the critique: this answer is too absolute to be adequate for the subjective question at hand.  Unfortunately, the people who designed SE decided early on that downvotes should not require justification, so people can and regularly do downvote without explanation.  I find it vexing, but there's not much hope that it will ever change.

Comment: I agree with @Aaron here. When I play it straight, without accents or additional context, I hear the pitch change at regular intervals as the 1. Even if I start on one of the A notes, I end up hearing the G as the 1.

Comment: @phoog I have to disagree and side with Aaron here on the question of this question's subjectivity. Granted, the OP has created a bit of an "angels dancing on the head of a pin" thought experiment, with a naked bass line rendered with absolute equal emphasis on all notes—but given those parameters, I think the answer is simple; the melodic change is the only "landmark" to suggest a meter, and the given example is simple and repetitive enough to force us into one perception.

Comment: @AndyBonner I can only think of the conductor whose name I sadly cannot remember who, according to one of my conducting teachers in graduate school, was so unable to deal with 5/4 meter that he conducted the second movement of Tchaikovsky's 6th with the first beat of each measure twice as long as the others, turning 5/4 into 6/4.  Such a person might well hear the pattern in question as s 4- (or 6?) beat pattern with the Gs occurring at different points in the pattern.

Comment: @phoog I heard an anecdote about a conductor: "Maestro, do you find it difficult to conduct in 7?" "Certainly not—one, two, three, four, five, six, sev, en." (Though in seriousness, I would argue that the "stretch it to fit" approach is different than "willfully hear the downbeat where you want it to be." My anecdotal data would suggest that adding a beat is a natural reflexive response in 90% of kids encountering 3/4 or triplets for the first time ("One two three-ee one two three-ee")

Comment: @AndyBonner - true enough! So many students when meeting 5/4 would morph it fairly soon into either 4/4 or 6/4. Both of which are in fact more natural - having even numbers of hands and feet. Where that puts our 5 fingers/thumbs though, I'm still trying to figure...

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of any emphasised notes, it's virtually impossible to say in reality.

The existence of that recurring G note, with the extra one towards the end would trend towards 5/4, with the added fact that that gives four lines to the music - a very common feature, against the five lines otherwise.

I'd really appreciate dv reasons - thanks!